# cant read file and use it with my code

Tags: python

i am using following module:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams

def makeNGrams(filename, n):
  variable_NGrams = ngrams(word_tokenize(filename), n)
  return [' '.join(grams) for grams in variable_NGrams]
```

with just typing in the text i want to work with it is working, but importing a text file doesnt work.

when i write the module like this

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams

def makeNGrams(filename, n):
  text = open(filename, 'r').read()
  variable_NGrams = ngrams(word_tokenize(text), n)
  return [' '.join(grams) for grams in variable_NGrams]
```

and use it to open a specific txt file i get a huge loads of errors

how can i import and use a text file with this module?

Comment: Post your HUGE loads of errors here , we can help you better then!

Comment: ok i fixed it, it was a stupid mistake :( i had one .txt too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one of two issues. Your filename is either the full name and you don't need to append the `.txt` or it doesn't include the proper file extensions and you need to add it properly.

Option 1:

```
def makeNGrams(filename, n):
    # Note the difference here
    text = open(filename, 'r').read()
    variable_NGrams = ngrams(word_tokenize(text), n)
    return [' '.join(grams) for grams in variable_NGrams]
```

Option 2:

```
def makeNGrams(filename, n):
    # Note the difference here
    text = open('{}.txt'.format(filename), 'r').read()
    variable_NGrams = ngrams(word_tokenize(text), n)
    return [' '.join(grams) for grams in variable_NGrams]
```

Comment: the first option it is - i added a .txt and was messing around with this for an hour without realizing it

Answer (score 0):

when opening files better to use try except block. That way is much easier to catch errors

import pprint

try:

```
with  open('filname', 'r') as f:

    text = f.read()
```

except Exception as e:

```
pprint.pprint(e)
```

FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')